# Can't login with my user account, works only with admin account

Tags: user-account, login

I have iMac late 2015, macOS High Sierra. Till now it worked perfectly, but today I turned on my computer, it allowed to login into my user account, then I opened one app and it went to not responding. I forced to quit the apps, but that doesn't work and then turned off the computer. After that I can't login into my account, I enter the password and shortly the color loader icon appears and that's it. I made reset, tried safe mode, disk utility, nothing works. But everything works fine with admin user. Does anybody know what else I can try?

Comment: If you don’t have a current backup then do one. What happens if you create a new account - does that work?

Comment: Yes, that works. New user, no matter standard or admin, it works. @SolarMike

Comment: So, did you do the backup? Because I think you will need it... I would be making a new account.

Comment: When I will create new user, will I be able to get into folders like desktop, downloads, from the old user?

Comment: how did you reset ? login with admin user and reset your desired user account. I will also try to type the new password first on Note to see the keyboard combination too. There must be something weird.

Comment: Your machine is going off the rails. It could be  a hardware or software problem. Could be the drive is going bad. Check out Disk Utility to verify the drive.